# Does watching flightless species of birds count as birdwatching?

Tags: meaning

I recently came across someone categorising the watching of penguins as birdwatching. Does watching flightless species of birds, such as penguins or emus count as birdwatching?

I couldn't find any mention of flightlessness, either ruling it in or out, in the Wikipedia article on [Birdwatching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birdwatching).

Comment: Most birdwatching occurs while the bird is not flying.

Comment: @AndrewLeach detecting movement is one of the ways I notice birds.

Comment: You mention that they are still 'birds' so yes.

Comment: Can you give any reason why watching penguins, who are birds, is not birdwatching? Is it because penguins don't seem like birds (too round)? Or because the places where birdwatchers normally observe birds, namely temperate and tropical forests, is not where penguins are usually seen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/birdwatching), **birdwatching** is:

> the practice of observing **birds** in their natural environment as a hobby.

and [a **bird** is](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bird):

> a warm-blooded egg-laying vertebrate distinguished by the possession of feathers, wings, and a beak and (*typically*) by being able to fly.

So regardless of whether the bird has the ability to fly or not, watching birds is still called birdwatching.

Here are some examples:

> Your **bird watching** holiday is going to be a largely sedentary activity, so make sure you dress warm enough to combat the cold of the Polar Regions. Having to do jumping jacks to warm yourself tends to scare birds away (except for certain species of **penguins** who will find you fascinating). [Source](https://oceanwide-expeditions.com/to-do/experiences/bird-watching)

and:

> Whatever method these bird species may choose—singing, feather displaying, preening, feeding, nest building, or dancing—it’s all about the propagation of the species. When it comes to the Albatross, the Manakin, the **Emu**, the **Prairie Chicken**, and the Sharptail Grouse (amongst numerous other bird species); may the best dancer win! For humans, the courtship rituals of our feathered friends make for excellent **bird watching**. [Source](http://www.sandhillsmotel.com/the-mating-dance-of-birds-around-the-world/)